# Is $f(x) = 3 -\frac{2}{x}$ injective or surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $f: \mathbb R\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)$ = $3 - \frac{2}{x}$. I'm trying to determine if the function is injective or surjective. I'm not sure if what I've done is completely correct.

Here's my attempt: Let $a, b \in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, suppose $f(a) = f(b)$. Then

$$3 - \frac{2}{a}= 3 - \frac{2}{b} \Rightarrow \frac{2}{a} = \frac{-2}{a}\Rightarrow a= -b.$$

Therefore, $f$ is not injective.

To check surjectivity, let $y = 3 - \frac{2}{x}$, then

$$xy = 3- 2x \Rightarrow xy + 2x = 3 \Rightarrow  x(y + 2) = 3 \Rightarrow x = \frac{3}{y} + 3.$$

Thus $f$ is not onto. ${}$

Comment: How do you get from $3-2/a=3-2/b$ to $2/a=-2/b$?

Comment: I cancelled the 3 from both sides

Comment: Unfortunately, what you've done is not at all correct. In your proof of non-injectivity, you have an algebra error and it's not at all clear where your final conclusion comes from. For the second part, why can you conclude that f is not surjective? It seems that you've written a bunch of algebra and a conclusion that's disconnected from it - that's not a proof. A proof would have an explanation of how the parts come together.

Comment: @TiffanySwaby so, if you had $3-x=3-y$ you'd conclude that $x=-y$?

Comment: No, I'd conclude - x = - y

Comment: @TiffanySwaby But if $x$ were $2/a$ and $y$ were $2/b$ you'd conclude that $x=-y$ rather than $x=y\ldots$

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown So it would be -2/a = -2/b,instead of 2/a = -2/b?

Comment: @TiffanySwaby Indeed, it would.

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown Therefore, -a = -b and it is injective after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For injectivity:

From $$3-\frac{2}a=3-\frac{2}b$$

As you cancel $3$ from boths sides, we have

$$\color{blue}-\frac{2}a=-\frac{2}b$$

Try to examine if it is injective again.

Now for surjectivity, your goal is given $y\in R$, you want to check if you can find a non-zero preimage. If you can show a real value that it can't attain, then you have shown that it is not surjective.

Also, from your working, from  $$y=3-\frac{2}x$$

If you multiply everything by $x$, you get

$$xy=\color{blue}{3x-2}$$

Can you see what value $y$ can't take? (it is a small positive integer number)

Comment: y = 3 - 2 / x ⇒ xy = 3x -2 ⇒ xy -3x = 2 ⇒x(y-3) =2 ⇒ x=2/y-3

Comment: braces are good. $x=2/(y-3)$ is clearer. so which value doesn't have a preimage? what can you conclude about surjectivity?

Comment: So, y = 3 does not have a pre image and f is not onto

Comment: yes, $y=3$ doesn't have a preimage. If you substitute $y=3$ into $y = 3-\frac2{x}$ you should get a contradiction like $0=-2$. It is not onto.

Comment: Ok, you were very helpful!